# how to append data in each call react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I would like to know how to handle multiple call to action with different parameters.
How to append the data received for each parameter call in react redux.
Is there any other way to do, or for each `id` should have seperate action

```
action.js
export const saleSumm= payload =>
  queryApi({
    request: CONSTANTS.SALES_SUMMARY,
    url: `/api/detail`,
    encode: false,
    success: CONSTANTS.SUMMARY_SUCCESS,
    failure: CONSTANTS.SUMMARY_FAILURE,
    ...payload
  });
//reducer.js
 case CONSTANTS.SUMMARY_SUCCESS:
 case CONSTANTS.SUMMARY_FAILURE:
     return {
        ...state,
        SaleSumm: data, //should append data for each id
        apiPending: false,
        errormsg: errormsg,
        servererror: servererror || ""
    };
//index.js

fetchData = (id) =>{
  const body = {
    id: id,
    cn: "MY"
  }
return body;
}

renderData=(item)=>{
var mode = ["1010", "1111"];
mode.map(i=> 
this.props.dispatch(saleSumm(this.fetchData(i))))
}

render(){
return(
  <div>{this.renderData(this.props)}</div>
)
}
```

Comment: `redux-thunk` is nice for handling async API calls, you should check that out. Besides it lets you do exactly what you want - pass parameters into dispatch functions, like an ID. You can then write your reducer as you normally would, with the data being appended using the spread operator.

If you want to append the data without changing much though, you need to also spread the `SaleSumm` and then append new data to it.

Comment: @SomeRandomName thanks am using redux-saga, can you provide sample if possible